# Cloning an event object in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

How can I create a completely separate and new event object that contains all of the same exact properties as a given event object `e`.  So far I've tried the following but no luck:

```
function myHandler(e) {
   // ...

   e = e.originalEvent;

   // method 1
   var e2 = jQuery.extend(true, {}, e);

   // method 2
   var e2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e));

   // ...
}
```

EDIT: I will add more details to help clarify.  Very similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176724/) I am trying to do: `div.dispatchEvent(e.originalEvent)`, but doing so results in:

> DISPATCH_REQUEST_ERR: DISPATCH_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Events Exception 1

so in order to avoid this, I need to duplicate the event object.  However, this event object isn't a specific one (i.e., sometimes the `e` is a `touchstart`, `touchmove`, or `touchend`) and therefore it'd be easier if I could get a general cloning function instead of just hard coding the specific properties.  What I meant by "no luck" was that by trying the aforementioned methods and sending that thru the dispatch function I was getting errors.  Hope this helps clarify a bit.

Comment: updated. sorry, there was a typo

Comment: How about `jQuery.extend(true, {}, e)` without the `e = e.originalEvent` ?
And what do you mean by "no luck" ? :)

Comment: "DISPATCH_REQUEST_ERR: If the Event object is already dispatched in the tree." hmm...

Comment: Why do you need to clone an event?

Comment: Like I said, I'm trying to pass the event to another element, which is also similar to the sample link I posted.  Did you read my update? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had "good luck" with this code:

```
$.extend($.Event(event.type /* click, mousedown, touchstart, ect. ect. */), {
    which: 1,
    clientX: event.clientX,
    clientY: event.clientY,
    pageX: event.pageX,
    pageY: event.pageY,
    screenX: event.screenX,
    screenY: event.screenY
});
```

Obviously, this is everything; but you can add what you actually need in the other object. I create a new event here, because I'm actually forwarding an event to another element.

---

**Update**:

I use [jQuery Touch Punch Plugin](http://touchpunch.furf.com/) which basically maps click/mouse events to the associated touch event: touchstart, touchesmoved, touchend. So if you forward this event as the mouse event:

```
var newEvent = $.extend($.Event(event.type), {
    which: 1,
    clientX: event.clientX,
    clientY: event.clientY,
    pageX: event.pageX,
    pageY: event.pageY,
    screenX: event.screenX,
    screenY: event.screenY
});

// touch punch will convert to a touch event if needed
$('.some-other-element').trigger(newEvent);
```

You simply need to include the touch punch script on your page. This will also allow jQuery UI elements to function on touch devices.

references:

- [jQuery Event Constructor](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)
- [jQuery trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: I've added a little more info. Seems like we are accomplishing similar goals.

Comment: +1. It's probably the best to write own function which will copy all the attributes you need.

Answer (score 2):

The answer herein, labeled "[Just pass in the native event argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29154837),"

```
function (e) {
    var $event = $.Event(e.type, e);
}
```

won't work if you want to change the event type: jQuery will replace your specified event type parameter with the event type from the event object you pass. So this approach works only as a means of exactly cloning an event object. When doing so, I suggest using *null* in place of the event type parameter, as a semantic hint that the event is being strictly cloned:

```
function (e) {
    var event = $.Event(null, e); // clone event
}
```

Of course, you can always change the event's type value after cloning:

```
function (kind, e) {
    var event = $.Event(null, e); // clone event
    event.eventType = kind;

    return event;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Just pass in the native event argument

```
function (e) {
    var $event = $.Event(e.type, e);
}
```

Because all the properties that you can manually set already exist in the native event argument, and because the `$.Event()` constructor takes an object as its second argument, you can simply pass the native event argument into it.

Note: You must pass in the event type separately as the first argument for this to work, otherwise jQuery will just store your event object in `$event.originalEvent`.

Comment: great this should be the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
var eDemo = jQuery.Event("eventhandler", {
    target: e.currentTarget,
    relatedTarget: e.relatedTarget,
    pageX: e.pageX,
    pageY: e.pageY,
    which: e.which,    
});

var newObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, eDemo);// deep copy
```

Checkout Jquery event construct -> http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/